# How do I setText from AppDelegate to ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I have a single view application. It has myAppDelegate and myViewController. In a earlier learning project I did from a book, myViewController.h contained the following:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *textField;
```

And to display text to that label on the iPhone, it had you put the following in myViewController.m:

```
[textField setText:@"Hello World!"];
```

And it worked! Pretty! But...how do I accomplish the same from myAppDelegate? If I put that same line above inside myAppDelegate.m, inside:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I get an error: Use of undeclared identifier 'textField'.

So I can I print text to that same label inside myViewController from myAppDelegate?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer would probably be, "Don't...because the view controller should be responsible for its own views."

However, practically, you need to have a reference to your view controller in order to change one of its properties.  The syntax would be something of the form `[controller.textField setText:@"Hello World!"];`, but with your own variable name as the target.  The exact statement would depend on what's currently in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and how your app delegate and view controller are connected to each other.

Comment: I had to do: [viewController->textField setText:@"Hello World!"]; BUT I get an error that instance variable 'setText' is protected. How can I get around that?

Comment: Don't use pointer notation (->).  Use `viewController.textField` and if that gives you any errors, fix those instead of accessing the instance variable.

Comment: Add `@public` above the variable declaration in the view controller.